# Why do we use au versus a for 'to'

Tags: au

I am using Babbel and I see some sentences where it uses 'au' to mean to and some where it uses 'a' to mean to.

for example :

> From February to April is 'de février à avril' - Why is it not 'au' Avril ?

and

> From 15 April to 20th April is 'du 15 avril au 20 avril' - Why is it not 'à' 20

I am missing something simple I can't see here - Masculin/Feminine stuff I just need to 'learn' or something else?

As a relative newcomer to the language i find these grammatical things v v confusing  with multiple words meaning the same thing but based on either  subject or pronoun or verb etc.

But I will persevere and learn. Merci :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We almost never use an article in front of a month name. Rares exceptions are expressions where a month in particular is compared to the same month in general, e.g.:

> *Le mois de novembre 2020 a été **le novembre** le plus chaud jamais enregistré dans le monde.* [La Dépêche](https://www.ladepeche.fr/2020/12/07/meteo-novembre-2020-le-plus-chaud-jamais-enregistre-dans-le-monde-9242955.php)

Thus we say: ***De janvier à avril***.

Even if an article would be needed, that would be ***à l'avril*** not *<s>**au** avril</s>* so this phrase is technically possible:

> ***Du janvier** de l'année précédente **à l'avril** de l'année suivante*.

although we would probably use:

> ***Du mois de janvier... ...au mois d'avril...***

On the other hand, for dates, we use an article, e.g. *le premier janvier*, *le 14 juillet* so the phrase is indeed:

> ***Du 15** avril **au 20** avril* or better *du 15 au 20 avril*.